# FastAPI: combining BackgroundTasks and UploadFile gives SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument

Tags: fastapi

I'm defining and endpoint as follows:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response, File, UploadFile, BackgroundTasks

@app.post("/api/upload_file", response_class=JSONResponse)
async def upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...), background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    background_tasks.add_task(compute_secondary_structure_data, file)
    ...
```

So, basically, I receive a file uploaded by a user and I want to do something in the background with it, while I already send a response to the user (hence, the need for a `BackgroundTask`).

But I get the following: `SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument`

What is the best way in FastAPI to achieve what I want and combine those two arguments? Is there a way to add a default value to the background task argument? Or to remove the one for the file upload?

Thanks

Comment: Simple fix: move `file: UploadFile = File(...)` to the back?

Comment: @MatsLindh unfortunately it doesn't work because apparently the order of the arguments matter, if I put the file as second argument it contains an empty file instead of the one I send.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the ***`background_tasks`*** as a *keyword-argument* as

```
@app.post("/api/upload_file", response_class=JSONResponse)
async def upload_file(
        file: UploadFile = File(...),
        background_tasks: BackgroundTasks = BackgroundTasks()
):
    background_tasks.add_task(compute_secondary_structure_data, file)
    ...
```